# Pandas and reg ex, decompoising text and numbers into several columns with headings

Tags: regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column containing:

```
1 Tile 1 up Red 2146 (75) Green 1671 (75)
```

The numbers 1 can be upto 10
up can be also be down
The 2146 and 1671 can be any digit upto 9999

Whats the best way to break out each of these into separate columns without using split. I was looking at regex but not sure how to handle this (especially the white spaces). I liked the idea of putting the new column names in too and started with

```
Pixel.str.extract(r'(?P<num1>\d)(?P<text>[Tile])(?P<Tile>\d)')
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: so which ones are you trying to extract?  just `1 Tile 1`?

Comment: All the numbers and whether up or down

Comment: What numbers? Into what columns? Is the format fixed (there are always the same amount of numbers)? Do you mean something like `(?P<ID>\d+)\s+Tile\s+(?P<TILE>\d+).*Red\s+(?P<RED>\d+(?:\s+\(\d+\))?).*Green\s+(?P<GREEN>\d+\s+(?:\(\d+\))?)`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZYMp8D/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid an overly complicated regex pattern, perhaps you can use `str.extractall` to get all numbers, and then `concat` to your current df. For `up` or `down`, use `str.findall`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"title":["1 Tile 1 up Red 2146 (75) Green 1671 (75)",
                            "10 Tile 10 down Red 9999 (75) Green 9999 (75)"]})

df = pd.concat([df, df["title"].str.extractall(r'(\d+)').unstack().loc[:,0]], axis=1)
df["direction"] = df["title"].str.findall(r"\bup\b|\bdown\b").str[0]

print (df)

#
                                           title   0   1     2   3     4   5 direction
0      1 Tile 1 up Red 2146 (75) Green 1671 (75)   1   1  2146  75  1671  75        up
1  10 Tile 10 down Red 9999 (75) Green 9999 (75)  10  10  9999  75  9999  75      down
```

Comment: Hi, this is great.  What do the \bup\b do ?

Comment: It is called a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), which will allow only `up` to be matched instead of `dupe` which contains `up` within.